# Flash: Set up flash to not display things outside of the document screen?

Tags: flash

Is there any way to accomplish this?
I need to make it so that overlapping pictures or things outside of the movie screen will not show while I'm editing the movie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck View->Pasteboard in the Flash IDE and it'll crop your stage to your movie dimensions.

Comment: Stage, thats the word I was looking for!

but anyways, thank you.

Comment: After you uncheck the pasteboard view, is there any way to center the stage?  As soon as I unchecked it, it aligned to the top right corner

Comment: not that I know of - to get this same effect, I usually just go with the default view, then click on one of the colored boxes on the left of the timeline in a blank layer, then you'll have a stage-sized colored outline showing you where the boundaries are.